# Zend2 routes constraints like enum

Tags: php, zend-framework2, constraints, zend-route

I want to have a enum like constraint on a variable passed to of my project's route

e.g. variable `routeVar` only can be **optin** or **optout**

so lets say I want to have a url like http://subdomain.exampledomain.com/route/ which can get only one of the two following forms

1. http://subdomain.exampledomain.com/route/**optin**
2. http://subdomain.exampledomain.com/route/**optout**

the route configuration I've put together is as shown bellow and I have tried both `[optin|optout]` and `[optin|optout]+` regexes but no luck

```
'route-name' => [
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => [
        'route' => '/route/:routeVar',
        'constraints' => [
            'routeVar' => '[optin|optout]',
        ],
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => someController::class,
            'action' => 'someAction',
        ],
    ],
    'may_terminate' => true,
],
```

please note: this is a child route and it works fine to address the expected controller and action. I only fail to apply the the limitation I described using the  constraint :(

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot @AlexanderBalabin. if you like you can leave it as an answer to earn its reputation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you are looking for is

```
(optin|optout)
```

, the `[]` syntax is for character groups.

Actually maybe even

```
^(optin|optout)$
```

to make sure there are no extra characters in the value.